# Xampp - localhost not working

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

Although apache seems as "working" on xampp control panel,I can't reach the localhost or 127.0.0.1 . I changed 80 port to 81 but not solved.

httpd.cong -> Listen 0.0.0.0:80

My host file in system32/drivers/etc directory is like

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Last log in the apache error log is

```
[Tue Jul 14 22:54:33.141632 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2620:tid 392]     AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Jul 14 22:54:35.145746 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4708:tid 288]     AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Jul 14 22:54:35.188749 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2620:tid 392] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4708 exited successfully.
[Tue Jul 14 22:54:36.218808 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1376:tid 392] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 14 22:54:36.218808 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1376:tid 392] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
[Tue Jul 14 22:54:36.218808 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1376:tid 392] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Jul 14 22:54:36.470822 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1376:tid 392] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1296
[Tue Jul 14 22:54:36.984851 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1296:tid 288] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the port 80 is used by other applications on windows such as skype. 
Try changing the ports to 8080 in the apache>config>httpd.conf 
and to 4433 in the apache>config>httpd-ssl.conf

Sometimes your network maybe creating an issue. Try disconnecting the network and reloading the localhost. If it works, then its your network restrictions.